# CSS : Center Element in div containing floats

Tags: css, html, css-float, text-align

I have a div with three elements: A, B and C. I want A and B to be at the far left and right respectively and C to be at the center of the div. I float A and B left and right and aligh B to the center. Unfortunately, this does not allign C in the center of the div, but in the center of the space between A and B. Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jpo2017/sSERB/)

```
<div id="user-links">
   <div class="user-link1"> <a href=""> Timeline </a></div>
   <div class="user-link"> 5 Following  </div>
   <div class="user-link2"> <a href=""> <strong> + Follow </strong> </a></div>
</div>

#user-links {
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  background-color:red;
}
.user-link1 {
   float: left;
   margin:5px;
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   background-color:yellow;
 }
.user-link2 {
   float: right;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  margin:5px;
   background-color:blue;
  }

 .user-link {
   text-align:center;
  }
```

How do I center the element with respective to the main div and not with respect to the space between 2 divs floated left and right?

Comment: Using `display: inline-block` will prevent them from stacking but the content inside the 2nd column won't be "centered" without a specified width.

Answer (score 0):

```
.user-link {
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy as pie :)

Float the first and third to the left, and the second one to the right.

CSS Code:

```
#user-links {
    width:800px;
    height:400px;
    background:#CCC;
}

.user-link1, .user-link2 {
    float:left;
}

.user-link, .user-link1 {
    width:200px;
}

.user-link1 {
    background:blue;
}

.user-link {
    float:right;
    background:red;
}

.user-link2 {
    width:400px;
    background:green;
}
```

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MJ6vf/

Comment: i want the middle element to be centered in the div

Answer (score -1):

You want to add `display: inline;` to your `.user-link` `class:`

```
.user-link {
  display: inline;
}
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sSERB/2/)**

**Update**

I've modified the HTML to what I assume your after:

**[New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sSERB/3/)**

Comment: i'm afraid this is not working if instead of "5 following" we write a longer string ...

Comment: If you swap the order of the elements it still holds true. http://jsfiddle.net/sSERB/4/

Comment: @AlaaA.F. Where does it say they want a longer string?

Comment: @YaMo: i think when we want to answer a question, we must see every scenario possible ...

Answer (score -1):

if u do something like this with your CSS :

```
 .user-link {
   text-align:center;
   float:left;
  }
```

it will work, but you must give a width to it, because if you dont, it will lose structure in large entries ...

Comment: what happend ? my answer wasn't helpful ?

Comment: my answer isnt this bad :|